# Update data in the particular row in SQLite3

Tags: c, database, sqlite

My database contains 2 columns such as Name, PhoneNumber.

```
            Name       PhoneNumber
            Sam          123
            John          456 
            Sam          XXX.. (I want to update the phone number as 789).

    - Through UPDATE statement if I try to update the phone number for SAM as "789" 
      by verifying the name then in the entire database wherever SAM is present it 
      is getting modified.

    - My aim is to modify in the last row which contains the name as 'Sam'.
```

- Is there any way to update the phone number in the last row if the name matches.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <sqlite3.h> 

  int main()
  {
  char *sql = NULL, *pName = "SAM";
  int rc, phno = 789;

  asprintf(&(sql), "UPDATE table set PhoneNumber = %d WHERE Name = '%s'"
                 , phno, pName);
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);    
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
  {
    printf("Error: %s:Unable to ALTER the table\n", zErrMsg);
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: You need to provide a `WHERE` clause which can target the particular Sam record you want to update.

Comment: UPDATE table set PhoneNumber = %d WHERE Name = '%s'...  In my code, I am verifying the name but in my database, it might have multiple same entries. My aim to update the phone number in the last row.

Comment: There is no "last" row in a SQL table.  You need to tell us how the data determines the row you want to update is last.

Comment: @Tim thanks for ur reply by default the phone number will be null then I am trying it updates like this: UPDATE table set PhoneNumber = %d WHERE Name = '%s AND PhoneNumber  IS NULL'

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query Some lines of `create table ...`, `insert ...` and `select ...` are more helpful than a representation/description of db content.